# Array sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a array in javascript which looks like

> var data_tab = [[1,id_1001],[4,id_1004],[3,id_1003],[2,id_1002],[5,id_1005]]

And I want to sort them based on first value like..

> 1,id_1001
>
> 2,id_1002
>
> 3,id_1003
>
> 4,id_1004
>
> 5,id_1005

Is there any way?I can sort them in javascript..

Comment: Did you search "javascript sort array" ? Did you test something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Hey people, stop answering, we already have 8 answers to this easy question that Google instantly answers anyway...

Comment: I think we should have closed this as a dup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 data_tab.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0];});
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and
>   returns the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default
>   sort order is lexicographic (not numeric).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data_tab.sort(function(a, b){ return a[0] - b[0] })
```

**DEMO**:

```
var data_tab = [[1,'id_1001'],[4,'id_1004'],[3,'id_1003'],[2,'id_1002'],[5,'id_1005']]
data_tab = data_tab.sort(function(a, b){ return a[0] - b[0] })
console.log(data_tab);

# Give [[1,'id_1001'],[2,'id_1002'],[3,'id_1003'],[4,'id_1004'],[5,'id_1005']]
```

Comment: Forgot to add 'return'.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(data_tab.sort(function(first, second) {
    return first[0] - second[0];
}));
```

**Output**

```
[ [ 1, 'id_1001' ],
  [ 2, 'id_1002' ],
  [ 3, 'id_1003' ],
  [ 4, 'id_1004' ],
  [ 5, 'id_1005' ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data_tab = [[1,"id_1001"],[4,"id_1004"],[3,"id_1003"],[2,"id_1002"],[5,"id_1005"]]

function compare(first,second) {
  if (first[0] < second[0])
     return -1;
  if (first[0] > second[0])
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

data_tab.sort(compare);
```